# Permission Denied even after granting the Storage Permission

Tags: flutter, dart

I have added every thing required to download files to local storage still I'm getting this error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception:
> FileSystemException: Creation failed, path =
> '/storage/emulated/0/uth_content' (OS Error: Operation not permitted,
> errno = 1)

In Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>
       

  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

<application         
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >
```

In pubspec.yaml

`permission_handler: ^6.1.1`

My Dart File

```
@override
  Future<int> downloadZipFile() async{
     Directory extStorage = await _externalDataSource.GetExtStoragePath();
     if(extStorage !=null) {
         var response =  await _apiDataSource.downloadZipContent(extStorage.path);
         File zipfile = await response.zipFile;
         debugPrint("Downloaded file :" + zipfile.path + "Exist: " + zipfile.existsSync().toString());
         return response.statusCode;
       }
     else{
       debugPrint("Path is empty");
       createFolder("uth_content");
     }

  }

  Future<String> createFolder(String cow) async {
    final folderName = cow;
    final path = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/$folderName");
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }
    if ((await path.exists())) {
      return path.path;
    } else {
      path.create();
      return path.path;
    }
  }
```

How can I ensure that the folder is created, my android api is 30

Comment: The `/storage/emulated/0` path probably isn't pointing to what you think it is. Where are you actually intending to create your "uth_content" folder?

Comment: Hi @Abion47 yes thats the folder

Comment: The `/storage/emulated/0` path doesn't actually exist. It's a symlink that can point to different things on different phones, and not necessarily to a place in external storage. So again, I ask: where you are intending to create your folder?

Comment: on the internal storage

Comment: I'd recommend reading through [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) to find where you are trying to write files to and what permissions you need to write there. That being said, unless you have a reason to write anywhere else, it's generally best to keep your file location limited to the app-specific storage. That way, you don't need any permissions to write there, and it can be properly cleaned up if the user uninstalls your app.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

To get the permission use

```
if (await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted) {...}
```

**NOTE:** This permission is considered pretty risky so play store will reject your app unless it's your app's core functionality.

This is what google says

> Core functionality is defined as the main purpose of the app.  Without
> this core functionality, the app is "broken" or rendered unusable. The
> core functionality, as well as any core features that comprise this
> core functionality, must all be prominently documented and promoted in
> the app's description.

And if you are planning to create a file in an external directory and you are not able to find it, it's because you'd have to tell the device to refresh for the files. So I'd recommend using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/media_scanner) and passing your newly created file path to it or if you wanna do it manually with kotlin here's the code

```kotlin
    private fun broadcastFileUpdate(path: String) {
        context.sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(File(path))))
        println("updated!")
    }
```